# Excel replace only exact text

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula

Is it possible to build a formula in MS excel that would replace only exact word? For example:

**My apple is red**. I want to replace red with green, so it goes **My apple is green**.

I know I can use =replace

But if my sentence is: **My apple is reddish**. The formula should ignore and not replace red part.

I was thinking to use this combination " "&"red"&" " so it would change only if there is space before or after.But for some reason I can't make it work.

Edit:
This what I have

[image]

=REPLACE(A1,SEARCH(" "&E1,A1),LEN(E1)+1," "&E1)

If I add &" " after E1 it will break, because there is no space left.

Comment: Why not just `" red "`? Strange that it does not work. What happens? Does it replace reddish to?

Comment: `"My apple is red."` doesn't have a space at the end is probably why that doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I get an error, because there is no space at the end. Maybe there is a smarter way how to do this replacement?

Comment: You could do it with a REGEX in a VBA macro - detail on the how is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not actually have the `.` at the end of the statement then something like this will do it:

```
=IF(SEARCH("red",A1)+LEN("red")-1 = LEN(A1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," red"," green"),IF(SEARCH("red",A1)=1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"red ","green "),SUBSTITUTE(A1," red "," green ")))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Will also try to understand how the REGEX works.